# Crystal reports zero hour time is missing

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm using crystal reports for WPF project in VS2010, and when i attached my data table to report viewer report doesn't showing 12:00:00 AM time and rest of all displaying correctly.

I already checked date time in data table, date format in report file and its looking fine, I'm confused where the problem occuring any one help me out.

**Report:**

[image: Crystal report:]

**Data Table:**

[image: DataTable:]

**Date format from report file:**

[image: Date Format from Report File:]

Comment: What do you mean by zero hour?

Comment: If Data table having data like 06/26/2013 12:00:00 AM  1.003 its displaying as 06/26/2013  1.003 and here time is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution as explained below...

Created one formula field in field explorer and attached to the report as

```
DateTimeValue({DataTable.DateTimeFieldName})
```

I attached above formula field to the report instead of direct filed and its working fine.